# Python Selenium: Can `send.keys` be `=` to `input`?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So i have a little question: I want my small program to have to have an input of the users Destination/Hotel name and then sending the input to the website. Below is my code, please help if you know how to make the `send.keys` and `input` work. Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.booking.com/')

class Search:
    def Destin_Hotel_Name(self):    
        D_H_Name= browser.find_element_by_id('ss') 
        print("Enter Destination/Hotel Name: ")
        D_H_Name.send_keys(input())

Search.Destin_Hotel_Name(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

`send_keys` is a function that receives the text as parameter, you can't use it this way. The correct way is like this

```
D_H_Name.send_keys(input())
```

Comment: Hi @Guy, I already know that, but that's not what i am asking. I am asking if the function `send_keys` can be used as and `input`. I tried doing it like above in my code:  `D_H_Name.send_keys = input()`. But that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @stuum1. It doesn't work because you can't use functions like this. The only way is what I posted.

Comment: Can you please have a look at the post i've just edited? Do you to do it like that?

Comment: @stuum1. Yes, you do.

Comment: The thing is that it's giving me an error saying: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: @stuum1. Where? in `D_H_Name.send_keys(input())`?

Comment: Yes after running the whole thing i get that error and the program does not ask the user the question and doesn't let the user input the Destination/Hotel Name. Now do you understand the issue?